# Modifing a variable with itself + dictionary values / Pharo - Smalltalk

Tags: loops, smalltalk, pharo

when I run this code below i get on Transcript the values that I initialized both puntaje and div (0.0  0.0) the loops aren't changing them.
The dictionaries puntajePeliculas and contadorPuntajes have the data that I need I've checked beforehand

Any ideas of why it isn't updating the values in the loops?

```
puntajeDelDirector: director
  | auxiliarPelis puntaje aux div |
  aux := data.
  puntaje := 0.0.
  div := 0.0.
  auxiliarPelis := aux listaPeliculasPorDirector: director.
  auxiliarPelis do: [:each | puntaje := puntaje + [puntajePeliculas at: each] ]. 
  auxiliarPelis do: [:each | div := div + contadorPuntajes at: each].
  Transcript show: div; cr.
  Transcript show: puntaje; cr.
  puntaje := puntaje / div.
  Transcript show: puntaje; cr.
  ^puntaje.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update `puntaje` change

```
auxiliarPelis do: [:each | puntaje := puntaje + [puntajePeliculas at: each]].
```

with

```
auxiliarPelis do: [:each | puntaje := puntaje + (puntajePeliculas at: each)].
```

In other words, use parenthesis and not squared brackets around `puntajePeliculas at: each`.

To update `div`, instead of

```
auxiliarPelis do: [:each | div := div + contadorPuntajes at: each].
```

write

```
auxiliarPelis do: [:each | div := div + (contadorPuntajes at: each)].
```

---

**Explanation:**

In the first iteration, `[puntajePeliculas at: each]` (with squared brackets) is a block object, not the `puntaje` of movie `each`. Blocks get evaluated when they receive the `#value` message.

In the second, the precedence of `+` which is a binary message, is higher than the precedence of `at:`, which is a keyword message. Therefore the compiler will interpret it as:

```
(div + contadorPuntajes) at: each
```

which doesn't make sense.